# Accumulate Date Data Over Some Period

Tags: summation, time-series

Say I have a series of time points, spread randomly throughout the year

```
values = 1000;
mockdata = 
  Transpose[{ResourceFunction["RandomDate"][values], 
    Table[RandomReal[], values]}];
mockdata = Sort[mockdata];
```

**I want to accumulate the sum over a rolling two week period. This means for each date in the year the accumulation should include the previous two weeks.**

I can easily accumulate over the entire year

```
mockaccumulated = 
 Transpose[{mockdata[[;; , 1]], Accumulate[mockdata[[;; , 2]]]}];
DateListPlot[mockaccumulated]
```

[image]

Is there a easy way to do this, or should I go about finding each two week interval, checking if a value is within this interval, then summing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MovingMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html):

```
First @ RepeatedTiming[movingTotal14 = 
  MovingMap[Total, mockdata, {14, "Day"}];]
```

> 0.00637388

```
DateListPlot[{mockdata, movingTotal14Day}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Very fast solution!  What is the purpose of the forth argument ` {1, "Day"}` in `MovingMap` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, `{1,"Day"}` was a mistake (I wrongly thought the third argument works as _offset_:)) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is very slow - but does the job.

```
rollingsum[date_, datelist_, timerange_] := 
 Module[{daterange, datawithinrange, total},
  daterange = 
   DateInterval[{DateObject[DatePlus[date, -timerange], "Day"], 
     DateObject[date, "Day"]}];
  datawithinrange = Select[datelist, DateWithinQ[daterange, #[[1]]] &];
  total = Total[datawithinrange[[;; , 2]]];
  Return[total]
  ]

days = DateRange[Min[mockdata[[;; , 1]]], Max[mockdata[[;; , 1]]]];
days = DateObject[#, "Day"] & /@ days;
days = DeleteDuplicates[days];

accumulated = Table[{x, rollingsum[x, mockdata, 14]}, {x, days}]

DateListPlot[accumulated]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit more direct than @Tomi's answer, but still slow:

```
result = Table[
(* take all elements in the 2week neighbourhoud of md[[1]]*) 
zw = Select[mockdata,0 <= DateDifference[#[[1]], md[[1]], "Week"][[1]] <= 2 &];
{md[[1]], Total[zw[[All, 2]]]}
, {md, mockdata}];  (*440seconds*)

DateListPlot[result]
```

[image]